# Git/Github allow collaborators but keep control

Tags: git, github, commit

I want to allow some collaborators on one of my github repos, however I would like to limit them to their own Branch. There's only a handful of collaborators, and limiting them to their own branch would prevent erroneous commits/push's to the wrong branch.

Is there a way to do this? Am I going about this collaboration thing wrong? Is there a better way?

Thanks for any info, I'm new to having others work on my repos. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For doing that they just need to fork your repository, work on it and uploaded their changes. After that you, as the owner, will be responsible for accepsting the changes and merging them into your master or not.

If you are working with a **organisation account** what you want is quite difficult, due to the fact that you can only restrict access to the whole repository. Anyway you could create a group for that repo with some collaborators giving them admin rights and another group with other collaborators giving them just `pull` rights so that they cannot make undesired changes.

However for your case I think you need an organisation account

Comment: so skip the local branches all together and just have everyone Fork the repo and work on whatever... then issue a Pull request back to my repo (the master repo i suppose) where I can manage merge conflicts into a specific Branch (say nextReleaseVersion branch instead of Master). ??

Comment: What if I want to delegate merging tasks to someone else? Does this bring me back into a full circle of needing Collaborator's added to my repo? EDIT: I'm doing this with a free account on github, so not "organization" to allow me to assign different teams... but I think that's what I really need (but for a free side-project I can't justify paying for the Organization account)...

Comment: As far as I know you will have this problem you mention as long as you work with a public repo. Only you are the owner. For your requirements I'd suggest to create a company account. You have a little discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015579/add-another-user-to-project-owners-in-github