# Can two people put same Repo on Github?

Tags: git, github

**Context :**
*Me and my friend are working on a project, and It's under my account.
But he wants it to be shown as his Repo too, Currently, If I created the Repo, technically, I own it, but we both are working equally on this project, hence it should be displayed on his github account too.
I looked for forking, which is great but it'll make it look like he is working on **my** project.
I dont know much about the GitHub system, so the only practical thing I can think of is that we complete the project and at the end he re-uploads the whole repo again under his account.*

**Things I want to ask :**

1. Is there any alternative solution to this problem?
2. If not, will all the commit history and logs will be preserved if he clone the repo and re-uploads it on Github?
3. Any suggestions are welcome if you feel we have wrong idea about the Repo ownership etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to co-own a repo. There are however some steps you can take to ensure it is clear you are working together.

You can pin the repo to his profile and add him as a collaborator.

Repositories-> Click on the repository you want to add collaborators-> Click on Settings -> on your left, click on 'Collaborators', which is right below 'Options' -> search for the person you want to add -> finally click on 'Add Collaborator'

Additionally, if you wanted to go a step further you could create an organisation together for free. https://github.com/organizations/plan This is probably the closest option to what you described in your question.

More info can be found in the following answers if you want to take a look: [Add another user to project owners in Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015579/add-another-user-to-project-owners-in-github)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can  [customize profile with pinned repositories](https://github.blog/2016-06-16-pin-repositories-to-your-github-profile/). As long as you contributed in the pinned repository, you may pin it.
2. Pushing the repository to his own account will indeed preserve history.
3. Instead of pulling/pushing, he could fork the repository and then only push changes.

I would go with the first option of pinning the repository to his profile.